# Unable to get UDP traffic with socket module, but the traffic is visible in Wireshark

Tags: python-2.7, sockets

I tried following code to sniff UDP traffic which is coming to `UDP_IP` and `UDP_PORT`. My motherboard ethernet card IP is set to `UDP_IP`. The traffic is clearly visible when using Wireshark, but I had no luck with `socket` module.

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(256)
    print data
```

Are there any known limitation or am I missing something out?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you included a screenshot or sample data from wireshark showing the network data you think you should be receiving. Also, is UDP_IP a special address (e.g., 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1) or the local network IP address assigned to your computer?

Comment: Ethernet card on my laptops motherboard is statically set to `192.168.1.40`. Device which is connected to that Ethernet interface is sending UDP packets. These packets and the data can be seen on Wireshark, thus the traffic is definately there. From Wireshark I can see that source IP from port 50050 is sending UDP packets (Encapsulation type: Ethernet) to `UDP_IP` on `UDP_PORT`. But when I call `socket.recvfrom(256)` it just blocks trying to receive the data.

Comment: Bind it to 0.0.0.0. There is seldom any reason to use any other bind-address.

Comment: @user207421 is right. Always bind to 0.0.0.0 unless you specifically don't want to receive on any address. The reason why I'm asking for wireshark data is because if you are trying to capture packets sent from your own machine on the loopback, 192.168.1.40 won't see them, you'd either have to bind to 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0. Would you include a wireshark screenshot so we can see what's happening, otherwise we're just going to be guessing.

Comment: I don't want to capture frames which are sent by my machine, I want to capture frames which are sent from the other machine that is connected to my PC. On that machine it is also statically set that frames are sent to that specific IP (192.168.1.40). Could you please specify what information from the packet you would like to check out because it's pretty confidential.

Comment: So use `connect()` to connect the socket to that IP address. Using `bind()` as you are won't actually prevent what you're trying to prevent.